# Script PHP en proceso permanente?

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos, que tal. Gusto en saludarlos, yo por aquí nuevamente haciendo una consulta respecto a php (soy un novato en programación).
Estoy intentando hacer algo (que no se si se pueda) con PHP, espero puedan ayudarme.

Lo que necesito es que con una consulta MYSQL realizada desde php, se obtendrán varios registros y esos registros se almacenaran como archivo dentro de un directorio. Mi idea, es que si MYSQL obtiene 1000 resultados, los archivos se vayan creando 1 por 1, puesto que, al aparecer un registro en dicha carpeta otro proceso que estará corriendo permanentemente, lo tomara y procesara.

Resultado 1 - 1000 mysql:
 resultado 1 --> archivo 1 --> se procesa y finaliza dicho proceso 
continua php con :
resultado 2 ...
y asi hasta que se acaben los registros.

actualmente estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
 $select = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 where dato = 'dato'";
 $select = mysql_query($select, $link);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select){
     $dato=$row['dato'];
 $ext1 = fopen("/usr/src/test/test.txt", "a+");
 $contenido="este es el archivo que sera procesado con los datos $datos";
 fwrite($ext1,$contenido);
 fclose($ext1);     
 }
```

aquí ya tengo el problema, puesto que al hacer eso, crea todos los archivos en la carpeta al mismo tiempo. es decir los 1000 registros. No se como hacer que PHP quede en el bucle esperando la respuesta del otro proceso. Tambien podria ser que al finalizar el otro proceso, cree un archivo o registro en otro directorio y php (script1 al ver eso continue)

Espero se haya entendido, y si alguien puede ayudarme, desde ya les agradezco muchisimo.

Comment: Si el otro proceso se ejecuta rápidamente, podrías llamar al otro proceso desde tu bucle con system()

Comment: con un poco mas de detalles se puede planificar una estrategia, es un php que saca una foto de la base de datos y la manda a archivos mientras otro php lee los archivos y los procesa?. que pasa si la base cambia entre foto y foto ? son dos procesos independientes o se pueden unificar? si es solo procesar datos dentro de mysql podes usar EVENTS, para programr un php cada n minutos podes usar cron, y asi

Comment: son dos procesos diferentes, pero ambos necesitan de ambos.
ejemplo
Script 1
hace consulta y recibe 100 resultados, por cada resultado hace un archivo. Cada archivo es procesado por otro programa y una vez usado dicho archivo ahi recien puedo crear otro .. =/ no se si se entiende